# Como eu faço para alterar Imagem via VBA

Tags: imagem, vba, powerpoint

Olá eu gostaria de alterar uma imagem no Power point, eu **NÃO quero apagar e inserir outra**, mas sim fazer oque o comando indicado na imagem faz.
Alguém saberia como chamar esse método???

[image: COMANDO]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Alterar Imagem não está exposto no [modelo de objeto](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/object-model-powerpoint-vba-reference), então uma Função Definida pelo Usuário (UDF) pode ser criada para resolver este problema com uma função personalizada.

## Função

```
Function pseudo_alterar_imagem(caminho As String)
    'John SR Wilson
    'https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_powerpoint-mso_winother-mso_2007/how-do-i-make-vba-use-the-change-picture-function/dbf7c8cc-8168-4afd-9336-54a50ebda74e
    On Error GoTo err
    Dim oImg As Shape
    Dim osld As Slide
    Dim novaImg As Shape
    Dim ehImg As Boolean
    Dim ehAlto As Boolean
    Set oImg = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
    Set osld = oImg.Parent
    If oImg.Type = msoPicture Or oImg.Type = msoLinkedPicture Then ehImg = True
    If oImg.Type = msoPlaceholder Then
        If oImg.PlaceholderFormat.ContainedType = msoPicture Or oImg.PlaceholderFormat.ContainedType = msoLinkedPicture Then
            ehImg = True
        End If
    End If
    If Not ehImg Then
        err.Raise Number:=vbObjectError + 1000, Description:="Seleção não é imagem"
        Exit Function
    End If
    If oImg.Height >= oImg.Width Then ehAlto = True
    Set novaImg = osld.Shapes.AddPicture(caminho, msoFalse, msoTrue, 0, 0, -1, -1)
    novaImg.LockAspectRatio = True                'should already be set but worth checking
    If novaImg.Height >= novaImg.Width And ehAlto = True Then
        novaImg.Height = oImg.Height
        novaImg.Top = oImg.Top
        novaImg.Left = oImg.Left + oImg.Width / 2 - novaImg.Width / 2
    Else
        novaImg.Width = oImg.Width
        novaImg.Left = oImg.Left
        novaImg.Top = oImg.Top + oImg.Height / 2 - novaImg.Height / 2
    End If
    oImg.Delete
    Exit Function
err:
    MsgBox err.Description
End Function
```

## Teste

#### Em que a imagem desejada deve ser selecionada.

```
Sub teste()
    pseudo_alterar_imagem ("C:\Pasta de Testes\imagem.jpeg")
End Sub
```

#### Caso deseje selecionar uma imagem de um Slide específico

Neste exemplo o Slide 1

```
Sub teste()
    For Each sh In ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes
        If sh.Type = msoPicture Or sh.Type = msoLinkedPicture Then sh.Select
    Next sh
    pseudo_alterar_imagem ("C:\Pasta de Testes\imagem.jpeg")
End Sub
```

#### Caso deseje selecionar uma imagem do Slide Ativo

```
Sub teste()
    For Each sh In ActivePresentation.Slides(ActiveWindow.View.Slide.SlideNumber).Shapes
        If sh.Type = msoPicture Or sh.Type = msoLinkedPicture Then sh.Select
    Next sh
    pseudo_alterar_imagem ("C:\Pasta de Testes\imagem.jpeg")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia Rodolfo

O comando para chamar esta função no VBA é

```
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogInsertPicture).Show
```

Ele serve tanto para Powerpoint como Excel e Word.

Comment: Não consegui fazer isso no Power Point
1- "xlDialogInsertPicture" é só para Excel;
2- o Método ".Dialogs" não existe no PowerPoint.